# EF Core Creates 2 Columns For Navigation

Tags: ef-code-first, ef-core-3.0

I'm trying to link two tables together but EF Core creates two seperate columns for the same navigation property.

This is the ShoppingCart model. It should have the default ApplicationUsers GUID value as foreign key.

```
public class ShoppingCart : BaseEntity
{
    public Guid BasketGuid { get; set; }

    public Guid ApplicationUserId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser ApplicationUser { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<ShoppingCartItem> ShoppingCartItems { get; set; }

}
```

But it creates the table like the picture below.

[image: Design]
[image: Table]

How can I change the model so I can insure that only one navigation property is created correctly?